# mongoose ignore nested item properties with same key on toJSON.transform

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm new to nodejs, mongoose etc. I'm trying to transform my model on json convert process.

Currently, I'm using transformation function below;

```
Schema.options.toJSON.transform = function (doc, ret, options) {
  ret.customerId = ret._id;
  delete ret._id;
}
```

For a Schema like this:

```
{
    _id: "customer_id",
    name: "customer_name",
    items: [{
        _id: "item_id",
        name: "item_name"
    }]
}
```

The issue is, my transform function replaces all "_id" definitions even for the elements in "items" array.

Just like;

```
{
    customerId: "customer_id",
    name: "customer_name",
    items: [{
        customerId: "item_id",
        name: "item_name"
    }]
}
```

I've made some search on google but couldn't find any solution.

Is there any way to do that? I'll be glad if someone help me...

Thanks.

Comment: I've been playing around with it and looks like to work with toJSON but not with toObject: https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/mongoose-tojson-toobject-transform-with-subdocuments/